# localItemPrice in Google Analytics Data API

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is localItemPrice available via the Google Analytics Data API, or is it something that will be released soon?

localItemPrice is a field that exposed in the Google Analytics explorer UI, but it is not mentioned in the data API documentation.  Currency code was recently added as mentioned here, but not localItemPrice:

https://groups.google.com/g/google-analytics-api-notify/c/DXVGhDN-xos

I tried querying the dimension localItemPrice but the API returned an invalid argument error.